# Spring boot Application is not Shutdown if not able to connect to Stream binder

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am connecting kafka with Spring boot application using spring cloud stream Functinal style programming model.
I need to stop the application if the application is not able to connect to kafka binder.
Following are the properties I am using

### Spring cloud definition

`spring.cloud.function.definition=REVERS;UPPERCASE`

### Kafka client/binder configurations

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=${STREAM_ADDRESS}
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.min-partition-count=2
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.auto-add-partitions=true
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.auto-create-topics=true
```

Right now, the application keeps waiting for the Kafka node but in Up state

### Application Logs

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-21] Disconnecting from node -1 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 8486 ms.
2022-11-16 20:00:57.469  INFO [client,,] 23252 --- [ adminclient-21] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-21] Disconnecting from node -1 due to socket connection setup timeout. The timeout value is 16132 ms.
2022-11-16 20:01:18.626  INFO [client,,] 23252 --- [ adminclient-21] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-21] Node -1 disconnected.
2022-11-16 20:01:18.626  WARN [client,,] 23252 --- [ adminclient-21] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-21] Connection to node -1 (0.0.0.0:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Please help me with what I am missing and what I must do to resolve the issue.
Thank you!!!